# Does postEvent free the event after posting? (double free or corruption)

Tags: c++, qt

I am posting a custom event inherited from `QEvent` using `QCoreApplication::postEvent`. I had read that when using `postEvent` it is necessary to have heap-allocated event. But I am not sure who is responsible to free that.

So, I tried to use `std::shared_ptr`. However, when I create my event with `std::shared_ptr`, I got this error:

```
double free or corruption (fasttop)
```

Does that mean that `QEvent` is resposible to free the event, so that I can just create the event and not bother with deleting it?

Here is what the code looks like:

```
class MyCustomEvent : public QEvent {...}

std::shared_ptr<MyCustomEvent> evt(new MyCustomEvent(arg1, arg2)); // double free or corruption!
QCoreApplication::postEvent(targetObj, evt.get());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation for `QCoreApplication::postEvent`:

> The event must be allocated on the heap since the post event queue will take ownership of the event and delete it once it has been posted. It is not safe to access the event after it has been posted.

So maintaining a `std::shared_ptr` to the event after posting is incorrect, as the post transfers ownership of the event to the queue.

A safe approach would be to hold the event in a `std::unique_ptr` (preferably with `std::make_unique`), then call `release` on it when you post the event. That way, you can be sure that the resource will be freed if an exception is thrown before the post, and you won't do a double free. You don't necessarily *need* to use a smart pointer, especially in such a simple case, but I think trying to keep memory ownership exception-safe under maintenance is A Good Thing™.

```
// C++14 idiomatic exception-safe event posting in Qt
auto evt = std::make_unique<MyCustomEvent>(arg1, arg2);
// intervening code that could throw
QCoreApplication::postEvent(targetObj, evt.release());

// C++11 idiomatic exception-safe event posting in Qt
std::unique_ptr<MyCustomEvent> evt { new MyCustomEvent(arg1, arg2) };
// intervening code that could throw
QCoreApplication::postEvent(targetObj, evt.release());

// C++98 idiomatic exception-safe event posting in Qt
QScopedPointer<MyCustomEvent> evt (new MyCustomEvent(arg1, arg2));
// intervening code that could throw
QCoreApplication::postEvent(targetObj, evt.take());
```

Comment: Yeah, that was the thing that I had read I was mentioning :) So the thing that I have doubt on this is, if it takes the ownership and delete it, so do i have to bother with unique_ptr etc? Not just could I create with 'new' and then forget it?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use a smart pointer, but it's best to ensure that your memory ownership is exception-safe. If you get a double free when using `std::unique_ptr` you probably aren't calling `release` when you post it.

Comment: Ah, release behaves different from releasing when it goes out of scope?

Comment: `release` releases ownership of the object, so when the `std::unique_ptr` goes out of scope it doesn't `delete` what it used to own.

Comment: Ah sure. "You don't necessarily need to use a smart pointer, but it's best to ensure that your memory ownership is exception-safe." could be part of your answer. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how this adds exception safety. As I understand, if an exception is raised during construction of the Event, no memory will be allocated; if an exception is raised inside `postEvent`, the smart pointer has already released the Event and won't clean it up. This just adds another (useless) object, and has no benefits over a simple `QApplication::postEvent(targetObj, new MyCustomEvent(arg1, arg2));`. Or do I miss something?

Comment: @king_nak in such a simple example there may be no benefit, but if any code was added between calls or if any unsequenced operations were added into construction of `MyCustomEvent` or the `postEvent` call, we would lose exception safety. It's more about defensive programming.

Comment: What happens when we post to several targets? Is it ok releasing it after all posts?

i.e.: for (target : targets) { postevent(target, evt); }
      evt.release();

Comment: @MertMertce you'll need to duplicate the event, otherwise you'll get one `delete` for each target you send to.

Comment: Oh, do we need another event object for every target? Although that target does not mutate the event object, but just read?

Comment: @MertMertce yes, the queue takes ownership of each event you post.